# Integrating YUI tests with CruiseControl

Tags: yui, cruisecontrol

I am using YUI to test my JavaScript app, and want to integrate the test results into my CruiseControl build system. How can I use CruiseControl to run the tests? I initially thought about using the JUnit plugin to drive the tests, but that is a no go.

Does anyone else have this working?

(Please note: Changing either YUI or CruiseControl isn't an option for me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution, in the end, is a bit of a hack.

- I modified our test runner HTML page to post the test results (the entire XML object that it creates) to a PHP page, then to close itself.
- I added a PHP page to the build server (with a PHP processor attached to an Apache HTTPD instance) to accept the posted XML document and save it to disk.
- The unit tests are now run by a 'test driver', which fires up a browser with the test runner HTML page, and waits for the browser process to end.

This gets the output of the tests onto the local disk of the build server. I then merge the output file into the CC log by adding the following to the project configuration:

```
<log>
    <merge file="path_to_file" />
</log>
```

There are a few drawbacks, but are (currently) willing to live with them:

- Had to introduce a test runner app to the infrastructure
- Had to add an Apache server and PHP processor to the build machine
- Because only IE will allow a browser page to close itself without a user prompt, the build server must be a Windows machine.

Answer (score 2):

We have YUI Tests integrated with Hudson for our CI builds. The process should be pretty identical for CC, since we kick off the testing through a Java task in ANT.

We have a selenium driver (a java impl - we're working on making it public) which talks to a SeleniumRC instance, pointing it to the HTML files in build workspace to run tests.

You could take a stab at writing your own selenium driver:
http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#learning-the-api

The driver code talks to a SeleniumRC instance, and asks it kick off a browser pointing to the YUI Test based HTML test files from the build.

The HTML files run YUI Test Runner on load, and the driver injects code on page load, to pick up test results from YUI Test Runner when it's done running, and store them as files for Hudson to parse.

Regards,
Satyen

YUI Team